# Include column index name instead of suffix names when joining pd.DataFrame's with same columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Assume I have the following two `pd.DataFrame`'s

```
first = pd.DataFrame(data={'col': ['bla', 'blub'], 'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
second = pd.DataFrame(data={'col': ['bla', 'blub'], 'a': [5, 6], 'b': [7, 8]})
```

which creates these two

```
# first 

   col   a   b 
--------------
0  bla   1   3
1  blub  2   4
  
# second
   col   a   b 
--------------
0  bla   5   7
1  blub  6   8
```

Now I want simply want to join both on `col` which could easily be done like that

```
pd.merge(left=first, right=second, on=['col'], suffixes=['_first', '_second'])
# Current result
     col   a_first  b_first  a_second  b_second
-----------------------------------------------
0    bla   1        3        5         7
1    blub  2        4        6         8
```

However I don't really want to have these column suffixes, I would like to have the column names as they are, but have a column index which states from which table it comes. Something like this

```
# Wanted result
           first   second
     col   a   b   a   b
-------------------------
0    bla   1   3   5   7
1    blub  2   4   6   8
```

Could anyone help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do `concat` along `axis=1` and use `keys` parameter to add additional column level

```
pd.concat([first.set_index('col'), second.set_index('col')], keys=('first', 'second'), axis=1)
```

Result

```
         first   second   
         a  b    a  b
col                    
bla      1  3    5  7
blub     2  4    6  8
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! Now I can access a cell nicely like that for example: `res.second.a['bla']`